# What does ''be' in this task mean'?

Tags: tense, terminology

**Rewrite the sentence below.**

> Paulo studies International Law at University of Oxford. (**be**)

I've been asked for rewriting this sentence with ''**be**'', which I don't know what it actually means. On other hand, we can rewrite it as

> Paulo **is studying** International Law at University of Oxford.

Does this stand for ''**be**''?

Comment: Yes, **be** or **BE** is a conventional way of referring to any form of the verb-to-be.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How? I'd be grateful If you explain it better.

Comment: It is a convention used in books on learning English and on English grammar.  You might find **SER** in a  Learning Spanish textbook used in the same way.

Comment: By the way, it's "been asked to rewrite the sentence".  You have rewritten it in the present continuous tense. Personally, I would not have given that instruction that way. I taught English a long time and have never seen that expressed like that.

Comment: @Lambie bad to hear! My teachers think that they know english, which is just being egoistic.

Comment: Yes, I remember your other question re Cuba......

Comment: @Lambie That's anohter question I'm struggling with! She still asks whether or not I live there lol! Even thought, am telling that it is temporary action, depends on the content.

Comment: You tell her this: I was living in Cuba in 1999 but now I'm living in Miami. I lived in Sarasota when I first came to the US.

Comment: @Lambie Do you have anything where I can contact you? Definelity, she will find a reason to not accept it.

Comment: @Lambie If you'd like to open a chat room on stack exchange, we can keep discussing there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75422/discussion-between-lambie-and-morata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Many grammar workbooks and sites used to note "**be**" as a general hint for tasks in English grammar.  This "be" is in meaning of the following auxiliary verb ("the verb to be"): am, is, was, were as the article in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be) proves.

See the example below:

[image]